# SharePoint 2013 Unauthorized exception for provider-hosted Apps

Tags: host, provider, sharepoint-2013

I receive "Unauthorized" exception on the host side for a provider-hosted App for SharePoint 2013.

```
Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
{
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Certificates were installed, Anonymos access was disabled. I can't understand the reason of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into the exact same problem before... i resolved it by implementing OAuth and have it redirect to the app main page with "write" permission. 
    Response.Redirect(TokenHelper.GetAuthorizationUrl("mysharepoint.com", "Web.Write", "myapp.com/default.aspx"));

Basically what this does is that it'll authentication the login user with your sharepoint site, once it's authenticated, it'll redirect (with write permission) to your app site.

Here is how to implement OAuth: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687470(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is High Trust App. If you have exhausted the tips at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179932.aspx, then there is an illformed SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer. You can find out all of them using the below PS. Ideally it should be IssuerId@Realm. If there is one which is not, then remove that. But remember not to remove first one which is for workflows

Get-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer | select Name,RegisteredIssuerName

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Check user in 'Request.LogonUserIdentity'. actually this happens when your user does not have access to your site in IIS.
so to set the correct user in 'Request.LogonUserIdentity' follow the below steps:

open your IIS --> Authentication -->Anonymous Authentication --> edit--> Specific user [ User which you get in 'Request.LogonUserIdentity']. --> iisreset

now user have permission to access your IIS site.